# Reinstalling an app via ADB sometimes causes data to be lost on Samsung devices with Android 13

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to uninstall and reinstall the Whatsapp application, while keeping the app data on the device.

To uninstall the app and keep it's data, I use the following command:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.whatsapp
```

If I manually open the Google Play app, and install the app from Google Play, everything works as expected, the latest version of the app is installed, and all my previous conversations are restored.

But when I try to do this using ADB only, by using the following commands one after another:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.whatsapp

adb install base.apk
```

(where base.apk is the apk I retrieved from the device after installing the app from Google Play, by using the `adb pull` command)

The process only works only 50% of the time (The first time it works, but not the second time).
When the process fails, it looks like the data is not available on the device - i.e I have to configure the Whatsapp app again with my phone number, download the backup from cloud etc.

I am able to reproduce this behaviour on several Samsung devices, running Android 13 and One UI 5.1. I tested the same commands on a non-Samsung device with Android 13, and the `adb install` command works 100% of the time there.

Is there any special One UI functionality that could cause this sort of behaviour? And if yes, is there any way to bypass it?

Comment: is this `50%` with various apps or a single one?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski after you've posted your comment I tested this flow with 5 other apps. This only seems to happen with Whatsapp